# Firefox & NPAPI plugins: can they be restricted (to be only used on certain pages)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, npapi

I've been reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Shipping_a_plugin_as_an_extension) and I know it doesn't mention possible ways to restrict access to an installed plugin, but is there some trick one can play in order to contain the usage of a plugin?

Comment: Hope I clarified the question correctly. [Why do you want to do that though? If your plugin gives the page special permissions, it seems quite scary - e.g. a successful XSS attack on your page means the plugin can be used by the attacked. Just something you should keep in mind]

Comment: On Chrome, it is possible to restrict usage of a plugin to an extension. Thus it is conceivable to craft a plugin with special "powers" and control access to these. I am wondering if the same sort of thing can be done on Firefox.

Comment: FWIW, there are some extensions that use a plugin, e.g. cooliris. I don't know if they restrict the plugin usage to the extension somehow, might be worth checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your plugin to query window.location and then refuse to work if it doesn't match up with what you want =]

I don't know of another way to do it, though.

Comment: hmmm... that's not exactly what I had in mind but it might be sufficient. Thanks.